# How can I prevent OS X from sending the computer name to a wireless network?

Tags: macos

When I connect to a wireless router, the computer name of my MacBook appears in the DHCP Client section of the router's firmware. How can I prevent it from being sent or otherwise have it show as blank? I'm running OS X Sierra.

Comment: As far as I know, you have to change your computer name to something else.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want the name to show up on the router?